# Why are 2D inertia tensors $2\times 2$ matrices when 2D objects can only rotate around one axis?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, vectors, moment-of-inertia

Why is the 2D inertia matrix defined as
$$\begin{bmatrix}I_{xx}&I_{xy}\\I_{yx}&I_{yy}\end{bmatrix}$$
and not just a vector 2 or scalar? I saw something saying that $I_{xx}$ is the moment of inertia about the $x$ axis and $I_{yy}$ is moment of inertia about the $y$ axis but doesn't this imply that 2D objects can rotate around two axis?

I can't find much on 2D inertia tensors and what I did find did't make much sense to me, so if anyone could clear that up it would be great :)

Comment: There are an infinite number of axes that can be drawn through and even outside a plane object, why do you think there is only one?

Comment: @Triatticus I am making a physics engine in 2D so I don't want the ability to rotate around any axis other than axis perpendicular to the plane as the physics is only supposed to be simulated in 2D. In this case why would I need the moment of inertia around the x and y axis? Thanks.

Comment: If you just consider the rotation perpendicular to the plane, you don’t need the moment of inertia around the x and y axis at all.

Answer (score 0):

In representation theory of groups:

$$ {\bf 2} \otimes {\bf 2} = {\bf 3}_S \oplus {\bf 1}_A $$

In practice, that means combining two 2D vectors you can create a 3 dimensional symmetric object, and a 1D (pseudo)scalar antisymmetric object.

So for the inertial tensor, you're just looking at the ${\bf 3}_S$ thing (note $I_{xy}=I_{yx}$, so you have 3 degrees of freedom).

That further breaks down into a scalar part, the trace:

$$ I_{ii} = I_{xx} + I_{yy} $$

which is just the variance of the mass distribution.

The remaining degrees of freedom are

$$ I_{xx} - I_{yy} $$

which tells you how oblong you object, or the difference between the principal axes, aka: a quadrupole moment.

Finally $I_{xy} \ne 0$ means you are not on the principle axes, and it can be diagonalized away by the correct rotation.

Answer (score 0):

The 2D case is just a projection of the general 3D case. 2D dynamics are very complex to figure out without understanding this fact.

Consider a body rolling on a fixed axis on the horizontal plane with $$\vec{\omega} = \pmatrix{\omega_x \\ \omega_y \\ 0 }$$

In general, it has an angular momentum that is *not* parallel to the rotation axis, since the rotation axis is not along one of the principal axis of rotation.

$$ \vec{L} = \pmatrix{L_x \\ L_y \\ \ldots }$$

To represent this relationship in 2D, you need a rank 2 tensor (matrix) with two dimensions

$$ \pmatrix{L_x \\ L_y \\ \ldots } = \begin{bmatrix} I_{xx} & I_{xy} & \\ I_{xy} & I_{yy} & \\ & & \ddots \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{\omega_x \\ \omega_y \\ 0 }$$

and you have to combine the above with the situation of a body rotating out of plane

$$ \pmatrix{\ldots \\  \ldots \\ L_z } = \begin{bmatrix} \ddots &  & \\  & \ddots & \\ & & I_{zz} \end{bmatrix} \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ \omega_z }$$

But if you do this, you are going to be missing the cross-contributions of in-plane rotation to out-of-plane angular momentum and vice versa.

---

To do this sort of "2D" engine, but include in-plane rotation is very useful (for transmission modeling for example), but it is really a 3D engine, with displacements along the *z*-axis ignored.

In summary you need:

| Quantity | in-plane | out-of-plane |
| --- | --- | --- |
| displacement | $(x,\;y)$ | ignore |
| orientation | $(\theta_x,\,\theta_y)$ | $\theta_z$ |
| velocity | $(\dot{x},\;\dot{y})$ | ignore |
| rotation | $(\dot{\theta}_x,\dot{\theta}_y)$ | $\dot{\theta}_z$ |
| momentum | $(p_x,\;p_y)$ | ignore |
| angular momentum | $(L_x,\;L_y)$ | $L_z$ |
| acceleration | $(\ddot{x},\,\ddot{y})$ | ignore |
| rotational acceleration | $(\ddot{\theta}_x,\,\ddot{\theta}_y)$ | $\ddot{\theta}_z$ |
| forces | $(F_x,\;F_y)$ | ignore |
| torques | $(\tau_x,\;\tau_y)$ | $\tau_z$ |